# Drawing a color filled square at the centre of a frame but the user decides the color

Tags: java, swing

this program should draw a filled square at the centre of a frame but the user has to decide the color. I don't know why it doesn't work.

SquareComponent.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SquareComponent extends JComponent{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a color");

        switch(input.toLowerCase()) {
            case "black":   Square s = new Square(Color.BLACK);
                            s.draw(g2);
                            break;
            case "blue":    Square s1 = new Square(Color.BLUE);
                            s1.draw(g2);
                            break;
            case "cyan":    Square s2 = new Quadrato(Color.CYAN);
                            s2.draw(g2);
                            break;
            case "gray":    Square s3 = new Square(Color.GRAY);
                            s3.draw(g2);
                            break;
            case "light gray":  Square s4 = new Square(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
                                s4.draw(g2);
                                break;
            default: Square s5 = new Square(Color.PINK);
                    s5.draw(g2);
        }

    }
}
```

Square.java

```
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.Color;

public class Square{

    public Square(Color color) {
        this.color = color;
    }

    public void draw(Graphics2D g2) {
        Rectangle box = new Rectangle(20, 20, 130, 180);
        g2.draw(box);
        g2.setColor(color);
        g2.fill(box);
    }

    private Color color;
}
```

SquareViewer.java

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SquareViewer{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        final int FRAME_WIDTH = 300;
        final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 400;

        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setTitle("Square");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        SquareComponent component = new SquareComponent();
        frame.add(component);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

If I run SquareViewer, the JOptionPane shows up. I write "black" for example. It shows a black square but with the JOptionPane in the background. Why doesn't it work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. A painting method is for painting only. You should never prompt for input in the painting method. The JOptionPane should be displayed in your main() method when you create your components
2. A painting method should paint the state of the component. For example, a JLabel paints the text when you use the setText() method. So in your case the `Sqaure` object is the property of your `SquareComponent`, so you need a way to add the `Square to you`SquareComponent`and then you save the Square as a property. Then the`paintComponent()`method simply paints the`Square`.
3. Your painting method should always clear the background before doing the custom painting. You don't, which is probably why you see the JOptionPane because the area hasn't been cleared. In the example below I extend a JPanel since is has default functionality to clear the background when you invoke the super.paintComponent().

Your `SquareComponent` class might be something like:

```
public class SquareComponent extends JPanel
{
    private Square square;

    public SquareComponent(Square square)
    {
        this.square = square;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        square.draw(g);
    }
}
```

Then in your `main()` method you do something like:

```
Square square = getSquareColor();
SquareComponent component = new SquareComponent(square);
frame.add(component);
```

The `getSquareColor()` method would be  method something like:

```
private static Square getSquareColor()
{
    String input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter a color");

    switch(input.toLowerCase()) {
        case "black":   return new Square(Color.BLACK);
        case "blue":    return new Square(Color.BLUE);
        ...
    }

    return = new Square(Color.PINK);

}
```

This is still not the best design. I would be nice to have your SquareComponent be able to paint multiple Square objects. Check out [Custom Painting Approaches](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/) for a design that will allow this.